# What do the circuits of this matroid look like?

Tags: co.combinatorics, terminology, matroid-theory, colorings

Given any hypergraph $H=(V,E)$ we call a family of sets $I\subseteq E$ "indifferent" iff there exists a map $\phi:I\to V$ such that: $\forall X\in I(\phi(X)\in X)$ and $\forall X,Y\in I(X\subset Y\rightarrow \phi(X)\neq \phi(Y))$.

Now my goal is to find some simpler criteria for determining if a family of edges in $H$ is indifferent, however this seems to be equivalent to characterizing all the circuits of a matroid grounded on $E$.

Namely I can prove the pair $M=(E,\{I\subseteq E:I\text{ is indifferent}\})$ must always be a matroid because if we construct $R=\{(v,C)\in V\times 2^{E}:v\in (\cap_{S\in C}S)\text{ and }\forall X,Y\in C(X\not\subset Y)\}$ then the free matroid $\mathscr{F}=(R,\mathcal{F})$ such that $\mathcal{F}=\{I\subseteq R:I\text{ is a functional relation}\}$ will satisfy $M=(E,\{\cup_{(x,Y)\in I}Y:I\in\mathcal{F}\})$. Thus if all the circuits of $M$ can be characterized then this would give a characterization for 'indifferent' families. But what do the circuits of $M$ look like?